# Detect hide/leave event of mobile phone browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, inappbrowser, mobile-phones, mobile-browser

I've surveyed most of the questions on the web but this still gets me confused....

My question is, how to detect hide/leave event of a website tab in mobile phone browser, my situation is **NOT** about closing the tab(like pressing the X button at the up-right or up-left corner), and also **NOT** about closing the whole mobile browser app directly.

(Previously, I have a webpage with a websocket connected to receive the encoded audio content, and then use `AudioContext` to play the sound)

Below are the two situations I've encountered.

> 1. When I press the HOME button and the mobile browser app hides.
> 2. When I click a url in the Messenger app or Facebook app of my iPhone, and press the Back button to go back.

the url link is opened in the in-app browser which made by Facebook directly, and when I press the back button on the left-up corner, the view jumps back to the Messenger window or the Facebook timeline.

In these two cases, I have listened `beforeunload` (and also `pagehide` event for iOS), but neither one is catched. And I have found that the websocket connection is still connecting and the audio is still playing. It seems like the whole page is still running somewhere(but you cannot see). I also tried listening to a div `:visible`, but it is still giving me `true` when I pressed the home button or leave the facebook in-app browser.

Is there still any way to detect these two kinds of situation? I want to turn off the streaming sound and also close the websocket connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer....

Page Visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API